# php mail() function not working with gmail

Tags: php

PFB my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Your information</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $x = $_POST['yourname'];


    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $msg="Your Name is $x.";
    $to='abc@gmail.com';
    $sub='Your information';
    $header = "From: ". $x . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
    ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com" );
    ini_set('sendmail_from', 'abc@gmail.com');
    //$email is entered as abc@gmail.com
    if(mail($to, $sub, $msg,'From:' . $email)){
        echo 'success';
    }
    else{
        echo 'failure';
    }


echo 'Thanks for submitting your information<br/>';
echo 'Your Name ' . $x . '<br/>' ;
echo 'Email ' . $email . '<br/>' ;
echo $msg;
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

i hqve configured my outlook 2007 with my gmail account(POP/SMTP). 
and the php.ini settings are SMTP= smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port= 587. These settings also match with the outlook settings.

Still all i get is "failure" prinited on my browser.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use "ssl" for sending emails from Gmail. YOu can download PhPmailer and can see the sample they provide for gmail.